# Is there anything we lose with MonoFoldable?

Tags: haskell, foldable, classy-prelude

[MonoFoldable](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mono-traversable-1.0.0.1/docs/Data-MonoTraversable.html#t:MonoFoldable) in the [mono-traversable](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mono-traversable-1.0.0.1) package seems to be able to implement all of the usual Foldable containers and more, for example, things like `Bytestring` and homogeneous tuples can be made `MonoFoldable` but not `Foldable`. My question is, do we lose anything from `MonoFoldable` that we don't have in `Foldable`, aside from requiring some advanced GHC features, making it slightly more tricky for instance writers and perhaps getting uglier error messages?

For example, is there some code which when using `Foldable` compiles but with `MonoFoldable` types are not inferred for example? Or anything else that makes client (not instance writer code) significantly simpler with `Foldable` than `MonoFoldable`?

Comment: It requires `TypeFamilies` while `Foldable` doesn't for one?

Comment: Not directly an answer, but `MonoFoldable`'s cousin [`MonoFunctor`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mono-traversable-1.0.0.1/docs/Data-MonoTraversable.html#t:MonoFunctor) is inferior to `Functor` in that you can't change the type of the things inside it. Same goes for `MonoTraversable`

Comment: I believe `MonoFoldable` fully generalizes `Foldable`, with the caveats around error messages and type extensions you mentioned. As @BenjaminHodgson mentions, the other classes in the hierarchy don't fulfill this. I'd be interested if someone has a counter-example to this, as I have no proof that this belief is correct.

Comment: @MichaelSnoyman, see my answer regarding polymorphic recursion.

Answer (score 4):

You lose parametricity.

A type `(Foldable f) => f a -> [a]` provides significantly different guarantees than `(MonoFoldable c) => c -> [Element c]`.

You can play with a free theorem generator to get some ideas of the properties, but as a simple example the former type provides the property that any element in the output *must* occur in the input.  This property is in no way guaranteed by the latter type.

Answer (score 4):

The biggest thing you lose is polymorphic recursion. Consider Okasaki's catenable lists:

```
data Cat q a = Empty | Cat a (q (Cat q a))
```

We can write

```
instance Foldable q => Foldable (Cat q) where
   foldMap _ Empty = mempty
   foldMap f (Cat a q) = f a <> foldMap (foldMap f) q
```

But if we try to use just `MonoFoldable`, we're stuck. The necessary instance constraint on `q`, `forall x . (MonoFoldable (q x), Element (q x) ~ x)`, can't be expressed in any usual fashion. It's probably possible to work around that with `Data.Constraint.Forall`, but it gets pretty ugly.

---

A smaller problem is that code may get more complex type signatures. For example,

```
osum :: (MonoFoldable c, Num (Element c)) => c -> Element c
```

strikes me as inferior to

```
sum :: (Foldable f, Num n) => f n -> n
```

The fix is easy: change the definition of `MonoFoldable` to

```
class (a ~ Element c) => MonoFoldable' a c where ...
```

which would give you

```
osum' :: (MonoFoldable' n c, Num n) => c -> n
```

Alternatively, scrap `Element` altogether, and use

```
class MonoFoldable'' a c | c -> a
```

which gives a similarly simplified signature.

Unfortunately, Michael Snoyman disagrees with me on this point. I may write my own wrapper package some time to expose my preferred API.

---

Update: now that we have the `QuantifiedConstraints` language extension, it's actually possible to express `Foldable` in terms of `MonoFoldable`!