# Why can't a non-polymorphic type implement Foldable in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, polymorphism, functor, fold, foldable

Say I have some simplified lisp-style `Expr` type as follows

```
data Expr = String String | Cons Expr Expr
  deriving (Show)
```

I can create lists as Cons-cells of Cons-cells:

```
Cons (String "hello") (Cons (String "World") (String "!"))
```

From this I would like to implement `Foldable` for `Expr` to fold over these cons lists - but that's not possible, since `Foldable` requires a type of kind `* -> *` (i.e. polymorphic with exactly one type parameter), wheres my `Expr` has kind `*`.

Why is that? To me it seems like folding over non-polymorphic types like in this case would be perfectly reasonable, but obviously I'm missing something.

Comment: It's because a `Foldable` instance is a kind of "container", and doesn't care what type is inside it. Your own type could be made polymorphic by replacing the `String` with any arbitrary type - and that wouldn't change anything about the structure.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39634504/is-there-anything-we-lose-with-monofoldable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> To me it seems like folding over non-polymorphic types like in this case would be perfectly reasonable, but obviously I'm missing something.

It is perfectly reasonable indeed. One way of folding a monomorphic container is using [`MonoFoldable`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mono-traversable-1.0.11.0/docs/Data-MonoTraversable.html#t:MonoFoldable). Another is using [a `Fold` from *lens*](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.17/docs/Control-Lens-Fold.html), or from some other optics library:

```
import Control.Lens

data Expr = String String | Cons Expr Expr
  deriving (Show)

-- A Traversal can also be used as a Fold.
-- strings :: Applicative f => (String -> f String) -> (Expr -> f Expr) 
strings :: Traversal' Expr String
strings f (String s) = String <$> f s
strings f (Cons l r) = Cons <$> strings f l <*> strings f r
```

```
GHCi> hello = Cons (String "hello") (Cons (String "World") (String "!"))
GHCi> toListOf strings hello
["hello","World","!"]
GHCi> import Data.Monoid
GHCi> foldMapOf strings (Sum . length) hello
Sum {getSum = 11}
```

As for why `Foldable` instances have kind `* -> *` rather than `*`,  I would put it down to a combination of simplicity and historical reasons. Historically speaking, `Foldable` is an offshoot of `Traversable`, and it is worth noting that, while monomorphic traversals can be useful, their limitations are rather more striking than those which affect monomorphic folds (for instance, you can't recover `fmap` from them, but merely a monomorphic `omap`). Finally, the Q&A suggested by Joseph Sible, [*Is there anything we lose with MonoFoldable?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39634504/2751851), includes some interesting discussion of potential reasons for not outright replacing `Foldable` with  `MonoFoldable`.

Comment: Thanks! I feel like most of the details still fly over my head, but you've given me some great pointers to explore!

Comment: @ionree In case it helps, a few more words on optics: one of the things they allow us is, so to say, supply substitutes for functor/foldable/traversable/etc. instances on the fly (and, as seen here, those substitutes don't necessarily have to be polymorphic).